# Rails Plugin Development - Cannot do Rails generate rspec:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

So I am creating a plugin and I did: `rails plugin new plugin_name` and that worked, then I updated the gem file to have `rspec-rails` in it and did `bundle install` and that worked, finally I tried doing `rails g rake:install` and was told I need to use the `rails new` command to create, essentially a new app - this is not what I wanted ... oO?

So what I did was copy the `spec_helper.rb`, as well as the entrie spec directory for another app over to this one, placed it at root level updated the spec helper to show:

`require File.expand_path("../../test/dummy/config/environment", __FILE__)`

But now it can't find the `rspec/rails` file and I only guess thats because I could not do a `rails g rspec:install`, so how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The previous steps seems all correct before your copying spec_helper.rb.

Before that step, do

```
$ rspec --init
```

Then the spec_helper file will be generated.

Then, go to the test_helper.rb file generated by Rails, copy the necessary lines such as requiring dummy app env to spec_helper.

Now you should be fine to run rspec.

Comment: That did not work as it cannot find, `cannot load such file -- rspec/rails` in the `spec_helper.rb` file ...